# Android constraint layout white bar at the top

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android application for a project I am working on.

I've implemented the functionality and have started designing the layouts. I've hit an issue that I can't seem to fid or find a solution to online. My constraint layout has a white bar at the top for an unknown reason.

I've tried converting the layout to linear, but the bar still seems to be there. Am I missing something really obvious or is this a bug?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".Login">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/registerEmailField"
    android:layout_width="371dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.469"
    tools:targetApi="o" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginPasswordField"
    android:layout_width="371dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.561"
    tools:targetApi="o" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/PicShare"
    android:layout_width="196dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/the_picshare_logo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.348"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic_share" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="371dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.665" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/navigate_to_register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/not_registered_sign_up"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.752" />
```

[image: Layout debug]

[image: Application when built]

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your theme attributes in `values/styles.xml` you can set your theme like this `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`. Or you can set title attribute like this `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`

---

in your styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

in your manifest.xml

```
<activity
   android:name=".YourActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. Not entirely sure where to set it though. I've added my styles file above.

Comment: Brilliant, top answer. Really appreciate that. Didn't really know what to Google but that has solved it. I've marked that as the answer.